# Sorting dictionary values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

i have a dictionary like this

```
{'michael': ['8', '6', '7'], 'robyn': ['2', '9', '2'], 'sarah': ['4', '3', '5']}
```

And I need to be able to sort work out the averages of the values and put them into a list with the users name from highest to lowest. I also need to be able to put the dictionary into a list where its sorted alphabetically and finally i need to have a list containing the users name and there highest score, this also in highest to lowest. I have been trying to do this but so far ive been unsuccessful so i appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you show us your code so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'michael': ['8', '6', '7'], 'robyn': ['2', '9', '2'], 'sarah': ['4', '3', '5']}

li = []

for k,v in d.items():
    li.append((k,sorted([int(el) for el in v],reverse=True)))

li = sorted(li,key=lambda x: (x[0]))

print(li)

[('michael', [8, 7, 6]), ('robyn', [9, 2, 2]), ('sarah', [5, 4, 3])]
```

Comment: thankyou this works perfectly, what about the alphabetical and size order of these values, would you be able to help with that?

Comment: @dansymail011 you wrote you need "highest to lowest" sort.  You want to sort alphabetically?

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear i need both it sorted in alphabetical order of the names and then in highest to lowest for the highest of each individual user. ill comment what ive already tried underneath

Comment: for line in dic:
        column = line.split("=")
        names = column[0]
        namess.append(names)
        scores.append(average)


final = []
final = dict(zip(namess, scores))
print(final)
sorted_final = sorted(final.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
print(sorted_final)
alpha = open("Alphabetical", "a")
alpha.write(str(sorted_final))
alpha.close()

size = 0 
if score1 > score2 and score3:
    size = size + score1

elif score2 > score1 and score3:
    size = size + score2

else:
    size = size + score3

Comment: @dansymail011, take a look please, is it what you needed?